# Confused about the angle to calculate when finding the direction of the vector

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, displacement

I was trying some questions and was confused about calculating the angles in some questions.
The question is:

> A man has to go 50m due North, 40m due East and 20m due South to reach a field.
> What is his displacement from his house to the field?

Here is my diagram for the question-
[image]

But the answer given for the question is-
arctan(3/4) towards the north to east

So i figured the diagram made by them is-
[image]

My question is why is my diagram and why can't we calculate the angle of vector with Y-axis not X-axis

Edit: This question was never meant to be an Homework Question, sorry if it looked like one. I was struggling with an concept i.e. find the angle of the resultant vector in similar questions and this is an example of one. It just happens to be a coincident that I understood the answer wrong.

Comment: The course this question comes from probably defines the positive x axis as zero, thus they might want it defined that way even if you're technically correct. It's unclear without any context from where this question comes from.

Comment: It is from HC Verma: Concepts of physics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that they gave must have been $\arctan\frac 34$ North $\mathbf {of}$ East. Which means that they are taking angle with respect to $X$-axis, rather than $Y$-axis. Your answer is correct too, you can do either of those things.

Comment: Well the exact wording is North to East. So if I am reporting my answer I should say east to North?

Comment: Yes, but they must mean what I wrote. Your first diagram is correct and the second one is wrong. The person moves first towards north, then east and not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Others are right. You are right too. And the book also.
See, $\arctan(\frac43)$ North of East is the angle with Y- axis.

And $\arctan(\frac34)$ is the angle with X-axis. (as $\arctan(\frac34) =\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\frac43))$

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm confused with the answer anyways as they asked for the displacement, which I would interpret as the distance between house and field, and that could be most easily calculated using Pythagoras.

Anyways, asking for the angle your first image is correct, it's $\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{40}{30}\right)$.

Comment: True that. I believe they asked for the angle of displacement vector, judging from OP's work.

Comment: Well the question was to find both the magnitude and angle but I was getting the magnitude correct so I didn't include it in the question.